# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds vs Apostol Volume II

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Next year I'll be taking a course in multivariable calculus. I was planning to study ahead of time using Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* since I had greatly enjoyed learning single-variable calculus from Spivak's *Calculus*. However, the course itself is taught from Apostol Volume II. What are the greatest differences between the two textbooks? Which of the two would you recommend?

Comment: I don't know Apostol, so just a comment. Spivak's calculus on manifolds is pretty dense, in my opinion. It is better to have something go through the details more closely I think. If Apostol does this, I might say that is better.

Comment: Apostol's second volume is a terrific book.  Spivak is much too advanced if you've only had a course in single-variable calculus, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having owned and read both of these texts, I suggest that you should stick with the course selection.  *Calculus on Manifolds* is completely different from Apostol's *Calculus Vol. II* and you would not be served by reading the former at this time.

In fact, without a background in multivariable calculus, it is doubtful you would even get beyond the first chapter of Spivak's text.  The prerequisites that are lacking include topics such as:

- Line integrals over a vector field
- Volume and surface integrals
- Stokes' and Green's theorems
- Differentials in higher-dimensional spaces
- Multivariable generalizations of the chain rule
- Vector and matrix algebra

Apostol will teach these to you at a level that can be appreciated by a mathematics undergraduate.  Spivak's text assumes familiarity with these concepts and shows how they generalize on manifolds, and how the fundamental theorem of calculus is a special case of Stokes' theorem.  The theory of differential forms is introduced.  I would not regard it as an undergraduate level text--that is not to say an undergraduate cannot appreciate the content, but rather, its terseness and treatment by Spivak is not suitable for an undergraduate textbook.

Comment: Thank you for the advice :)